# Google Maps API Key is not working in Salesforce

Tags: api, google-maps, salesforce, api-key

We are currently implementing Salesforce for a customer and he would like to use Google Maps (via Visualforce Page) to be able to see the Accounts on the map.

For the Demo-Purpose i have used my personal-privat-Key and it was working fine. But for the Business Process - as far as i understand - our client has to have a business key: https://developers.google.com/maps/pricing-and-plans/

Now they tell us they already have Maps APIs Premium Plan and provided us with the Key - BUT this Key is not working. What could be the issue here?

I would provide more information in a private message like Client ID and ClientKey.

Comment: Any error message in the console?

Comment: Have they enabled all the required services/APIs on their key (the same ones you activated on yours)?  Have they allowed the URL you are using for testing?  Are you loading the API correctly for a premium plan?  Theoretically, premium plans come with support directly from Google, you might try that support channel.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the client ID in the Maps JavaScript API calls as specified in the documentation:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key#client-id

You have to register authorized URLs in the Cloud support portal as explained in this section of the documentation:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key#registering-authorized-urls

Your client should have access to Cloud support portal as a Premium plan user. The easiest way to check which URL/path should be authorized is to review the value of the JavaScript's `window.location.href` in your application when you are loading Maps JS API. This value is the URL/path that you or your client have to enable in the support portal.

Anyway, if you experience any issue with Premium plan you can reach out to Google support team as specified in this document:

https://developers.google.com/maps/premium/support#contact-support

I hope this helps!